# NHibernate Create Criteria with 3 Inner Joined Tables

Tags: sql, nhibernate, join

I'm trying to reproduce this SQL statement using NH DetachedCriteria but struggling to get all 3 inner join statements working.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.ProjectID = b.ProjectID 
INNER JOIN TableC c ON b.OutlineAgreementID = c.OutlineAgreementID 
INNER JOIN TableE e ON a.estimateid = e.estimateid 
WHERE (b.ArchiveStatusID = 1)
AND (b.DateDeleted IS NULL)
AND (c.OutlineAgreementID = 14)
AND (e.PaymentStatusID = 5) 
AND (e.TransferStatus = 1 OR e.TransferId IS NULL)
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: the inner joins are correct. What is the problem?

Comment: It's not the SQL that's the problem is the conversion to NH DetachedCriteria syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = DetachedCriteria.For<A>()
    .CreateAlias("Estimate", "estimate")
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("estimate.PaymentStatus.Id", 5))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("estimate.TransferStatus", null) || Restrictions.Eq("estimate.TransferStatus", TransferStatus.WhateverIs1)) 
    .CreateCriteria("Project", JoinType.InnerJoin)
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ArchiveStatus.Id", 1))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("DateDeleted", null))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("OutlineAgreement.Id", 14))
    .List<A>();
```